# Recursively add to an array

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm struggling to understand a problem that i've got with recursion where by I am traversing down a hiearchy in only one direction and adding all the children of each parent to an array.

However I can't quite work out the best way to continuously add to that array while using recursion.

Here is what my function looks like so far. I'd appreciate it hugely if someone could push me in the right direction with this.

```
function getTaxChildrenList($cat, $data){

    $next = get_terms('location_types', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0&parent='.$cat);

    if(count($next)){
        $result = array();
        foreach($next as $next_key => $next_level){
            $result[$next_level->term_id] = $this->getTaxChildrenList($next_level->term_id, $result);
        }
    }

    return $result;

}
```

I now have the structure being returned as I want but need to actually add the objects of each of these children to the key which i'm guessing might be my base case.

Screenshot -> http://cl.ly/image/1z1v2S243f3H

Comment: Where is the second parameter in your call `$this->getTaxChildrenList($next_level->term_id);` ? You need to pass result to "add" the result and not replacing...

Comment: A recursive function has to have a base case. What is the base case here? At the moment, $result will always be empty.

Comment: JLRishe I think you're right. The base case would just be adding to the array and returning I guess...?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? add all values to one array? or having one array with values and other arrays in it?

Comment: Check the screenshot I just added. Gives a good representation.

Comment: Could you show us what the expected result is supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
function getTaxChildrenList($cat) { //no second parameter
  $next = get_terms('location_types', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0&parent='.$cat);
  $result = array();
  //base case would be count($next) == 0
  if(count($next)){
    foreach($next as $next_level){
      //add recursively arrays
      $recur = $this->getTaxChildrenList($next_level->term_id);
      if(count($recur) == 0)
        $result[$next_level->term_id] = $next_level;
      else
        $result[$next_level->term_id] = $recur;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: luk2302 you have done roughly the same as me which is good. What I need to do is actually add the object stored at $next_level to the array as well so that each level is not just empty.

Comment: So each term_id rather than being an empty array with the term_id in the key would actually have the relevant term_id data stored against it. Really close though.

Answer (score 0):

So perhaps you need something like this:

```
function getTaxChildrenList($cat){

    $next = get_terms('location_types', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0&parent='.$cat);

    $result = array();
    if(count($next)){
        foreach($next as $next_key => $next_level){
            $result[$next_level->term_id] = 
                 array("data" => $next_level->something,
                       "children" => $this->getTaxChildrenList($next_level->term_id));
        }
    }

    return $result;

}
```

Is it something like that?

Comment: JLRishe this turned out to be exactly what I needed. I think. :)